# POJO as a BootStrapNotifier instead of Application

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, altbeacon

I am using a POJO as a BootStrapNotifier instead of Application class. The POJO has reference to the context. Will background detection start in this way? 
I am also using this class as MonitorNotifier when the app is in foreground. 
Is it mandatory to use BootStrapNotifier and RangeNotifier in the same class like shown in the Reference Application?
Is this a correct approach? If the app is killed, will the beacon detection start only when power is connected or disconnected or re booted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a POJO to receive the callbacks from a RegionBootsrap, but you must still use the `onCreate` method of an Android `Application` class to construct this POJO and set it up.

The `Application` class is needed because its `onCreate` method is the first user-executable code that executes when an Android application starts up.  The Android Beacon Library’s `RegionBootstrap` works because the library sets up a broadcast receiver that looks for `BOOT_COMPLETED`, `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` events.  This broadcast receiver doesn’t do much, but if the app is not running when one of these events happens, it causes the `Application` class’ `onCreate` method to get executed.  It is the creation of a `RegionBootstrap` at this time that causes beacon scanning to start in the background and then notify user code when beacons of interest are located.

The code below shows how you set up a POJO called `MyPojo` to receive the callbacks from the RegionBootstrap, and register that POJO in the `Application`’s `onCreate` method.  The first parameter of the `RegionBootstrap` is the class that will receive the callbacks when beacons are detected.

You can use a POJO like this to set up ranging or do anything else you want -- there is no reason that such code has to reside in an Android `Application` class.

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo(this);
    Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
            null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(myPojo, region);
}

...

public class MyPojo implements BootstrapNotifier {
  private Context mContext;
  public MyPojo(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
  }
  public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return mContext;
  }
  public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    ...
  }
  public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    ...
  }
  public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to have the RegionBootStrap as an instance variable of the Application object. I do have RegionBootStrap this as part of a different class and still maintain it as a reference. Will this still work? I am not seeing any code in RegionBootStrap that starts the application. The whole point is I don't have any code related to BeaconDetection in Application class. However I will still be able to make an instance of RegionBootStrap available in OnCreate of application class. Should this suffice?

Comment: That should be fine as long as you:  (1) Execute code that causes the  `RegionBootstrap` instance to be constructed in the `Application`'s `onCreate` method.  (2) maintain a reference to the `RegionBootstrap` so it does not get garbage collected.